# How to write mysql query to order list grouped by parent-children using mysql loop?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have a User table which has the following columns:

- id
- name
- parent_id
- level

I want to order this table as ancestry(https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). Without adding ancestry column in user table,Is there way to create temporary ancestry column in Mysql.

**[UPDATE]**

I want to list the users in mysql ordered by temporary column ancestry which should have value for each user hierarchy based on its 'parent_id'.

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of levels or is this dynamic?

Comment: @meewoK I need a mysql query with temprory column 'ancestry' with value for each user hierarchy.

Comment: Can you use VIEWS?? [more info here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Comment: @Achaius Yes.. I was wondering if you have a maximum number of levels / descendants.

Comment: @meewoK In my user table the maximum level is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article... I think it is exactly what your looking for:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/19/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql-adding-ancestry-chains/

This describes how to make/use a heirarchical query to get the ancestry of a node within a tree structure.

### Update

Since you have a limited amount of levels a query like the one below would do the job.
The below query is for 7 levels, though it needs optimization as it is a working rough/draft.

```
select
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(ancestry, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(ancestry) - 1), ',', -1) as ID,
SUBSTRING(ancestry, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(ancestry) - 1) as Ancestry
from
(
  select 
  concat(
  IF(NOT u1.id IS NULL,concat(u1.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u2.id IS NULL,concat(u2.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u3.id IS NULL,concat(u3.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u4.id IS NULL,concat(u4.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u5.id IS NULL,concat(u5.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u6.id IS NULL,concat(u6.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u7.id IS NULL,concat(u7.id,','),''),
  IF(NOT u8.id IS NULL,concat(u8.id,','),'')
  ) as ancestry
  from User u1 
  left join User u2 on u1.id = u2.parent_id
  left join User u3 on u2.id = u3.parent_id
  left join User u4 on u3.id = u4.parent_id
  left join User u5 on u4.id = u5.parent_id
  left join User u6 on u5.id = u6.parent_id
  left join User u7 on u6.id = u7.parent_id
  left join User u8 on u7.id = u8.parent_id
)
as ancestryTable;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c1f/46

### Update - optimized version and corrected

```
select ID, ancestry
from
(
  select 
  u8.ID as ID,  
    concat(
    IF(u1.id IS NULL,'', IF(u2.id IS NULL,u1.id,concat(u1.id,','))),
    IF(u2.id IS NULL,'', IF(u3.id IS NULL,u2.id,concat(u2.id,','))),
    IF(u3.id IS NULL,'', IF(u4.id IS NULL,u3.id,concat(u3.id,','))),
    IF(u4.id IS NULL,'', IF(u5.id IS NULL,u4.id,concat(u4.id,','))),
    IF(u5.id IS NULL,'', IF(u6.id IS NULL,u5.id,concat(u5.id,','))),
    IF(u6.id IS NULL,'', IF(u7.id IS NULL,u6.id,concat(u6.id,','))),
    IF(u7.id IS NULL,'', IF(u8.id IS NULL,u7.id,concat(u7.id,','))),
    IF(u8.id IS NULL,'',u8.id)
    )as ancestry, 
     u1.id as a1,  u2.id as a2,  u3.id as a3,  u4.id as a4,
     u5.id as a5,  u6.id as a6,  u7.id as a7,  u8.id as a8
    from User u1 
    right join User u2 on  u2.parent_id = u1.id
    right join User u3 on  u3.parent_id = u2.id
    right join User u4 on  u4.parent_id = u3.id
    right join User u5 on  u5.parent_id = u4.id
    right join User u6 on  u6.parent_id = u5.id
    right join User u7 on  u7.parent_id = u6.id
    right join User u8 on  u8.parent_id = u7.id       
) as Ancestry
order by ancestry.ancestry
```

JSFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c1f/105

Comment: I can't able to understand this. Is there a simple way to form ancestry string?